# How to show all shared libraries used by executables in Linux?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'd like to know which libraries are used by executables on my system. More specifically, I'd like to rank which libraries are used the most, along with the binaries that use them. How can I do this?

Comment: You will probably not be able to get an exact number if the executables use `dlopen`.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

1. Use `ldd` to list shared libraries for each executable.
2. Cleanup the output
3. Sort, compute counts, sort by count

To find the answer for all executables in the "/bin" directory:

```
find /bin -type f -perm /a+x -exec ldd {} \; \
| grep so \
| sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d' \
| sed -e 's/\t//' \
| sed -e 's/.*=..//' \
| sed -e 's/ (0.*)//' \
| sort \
| uniq -c \
| sort -n
```

Change "/bin" above to "/" to search all directories.

Output (for just the /bin directory) will look something like this:

```
  1 /lib64/libexpat.so.0
  1 /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
  1 /lib64/libnsl.so.1
  1 /lib64/libpcre.so.0
  1 /lib64/libproc-3.2.7.so
  1 /usr/lib64/libbeecrypt.so.6
  1 /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1
  1 /usr/lib64/libelf.so.1
  1 /usr/lib64/libpopt.so.0
  1 /usr/lib64/librpm-4.4.so
  1 /usr/lib64/librpmdb-4.4.so
  1 /usr/lib64/librpmio-4.4.so
  1 /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
  1 /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
  1 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1
  2 /lib64/libasound.so.2
  2 /lib64/libblkid.so.1
  2 /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02
  2 /lib64/libpam_misc.so.0
  2 /lib64/libpam.so.0
  2 /lib64/libuuid.so.1
  3 /lib64/libaudit.so.0
  3 /lib64/libcrypt.so.1
  3 /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3
  4 /lib64/libresolv.so.2
  4 /lib64/libtermcap.so.2
  5 /lib64/libacl.so.1
  5 /lib64/libattr.so.1
  5 /lib64/libcap.so.1
  6 /lib64/librt.so.1
  7 /lib64/libm.so.6
  9 /lib64/libpthread.so.0
 13 /lib64/libselinux.so.1
 13 /lib64/libsepol.so.1
 22 /lib64/libdl.so.2
 83 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
 83 /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Edit - Removed "grep -P"

Comment: This is a great answer (I've up-voted it) but can you explain the "grep -P '\t.*so'" command? According to man, this interprets the pattern as a perl regexp, but my version of grep doesn't support it (man indicates this is a general issue). What bit of the regexp is perl-specific?

Comment: I think you may need to use `ldd -v`

Comment: Be aware that `ldd` actually runs the executable with a special environment variable, and the Linux dynamic linker recognizes this flag and just outputs the libraries rather than running the executable. Look at the source to `ldd`; on my system, it's a bash script. If the executable is statically linked and uses syscalls, and specifies a different loader, it can do arbitrary evil things. So don't use `ldd` on an executable you don't trust.

Comment: 'ldd' doesn't work for me on cross-compiled binaries.  The question is about finding the libraries used by programs on the current system (that would be native programs, as phrased). This is a good answer for that.  However, I thought I'd mention that you need to use something else if looking for the shared libs for programs for a different system ('readelf' mentioned in another answer, worked for me)

Comment: This is a big empty output in my case : /

Answer (score 96):

I didn't have ldd on my ARM toolchain so I used objdump:

$(CROSS_COMPILE)objdump -p

For instance:

```
objdump -p /usr/bin/python:

Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libdl.so.2
  NEEDED               libutil.so.1
  NEEDED               libssl.so.1.0.0
  NEEDED               libcrypto.so.1.0.0
  NEEDED               libz.so.1
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  INIT                 0x0000000000416a98
  FINI                 0x000000000053c058
  GNU_HASH             0x0000000000400298
  STRTAB               0x000000000040c858
  SYMTAB               0x0000000000402aa8
  STRSZ                0x0000000000006cdb
  SYMENT               0x0000000000000018
  DEBUG                0x0000000000000000
  PLTGOT               0x0000000000832fe8
  PLTRELSZ             0x0000000000002688
  PLTREL               0x0000000000000007
  JMPREL               0x0000000000414410
  RELA                 0x0000000000414398
  RELASZ               0x0000000000000078
  RELAENT              0x0000000000000018
  VERNEED              0x0000000000414258
  VERNEEDNUM           0x0000000000000008
  VERSYM               0x0000000000413534
```

Comment: This should be safe too, unlike `ldd` which shouldn't be used on untrusted executables.

Comment: Also, `obbjdump -p` shows additional information like the `RPATH`, which may be of help when investigating dynamic linking issues with your executable.

Comment: +1 for the method that is actually safe and reliable (I've somehow got a system where `musl-gcc` regularly produces binaries such that calling `ldd` on the binary *just executes the binary*, so nowadays I am regularly reminded of just how unsafe `ldd` is).

Comment: ldd and objdump -p have different outputs (ldd outputs more libs)

Comment: I _did_ have `ldd` on my toolcahin, but it unhelpfully just said (lied?) `not a dynamic executable`, vs. this, which actually made it spill the beans in the `DYNAMIC SECTION` as you show above.

Answer (score 67):

On Linux I use:

```
lsof -P -T -p Application_PID
```

This works better than `ldd` when the executable uses a [non default loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253170/checking-shared-libraries-for-non-default-loaders)

Comment: Used this to find out if [mariadb was actually using tc-malloc](https://github.com/blog/1422-tcmalloc-and-mysql), which gets loaded by LD_PRELOAD. Works great.

Comment: I was looking for something that would show me '.so' for a given pid. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: ldd and objdump -p have different outputs (ldd outputs more libs)

Comment: @ychaouche in this old answer I pointed out that lsof is better than ldd, in specific situations, I never mentioned objdump. Am I missing something?

Comment: @FabianoTarlao, oh sorry, I've added my comment to the wrong answere ! the comment was for this answere https://stackoverflow.com/a/15520982/212044

Answer (score 65):

to learn what libraries a binary uses, use ldd

```
ldd path/to/the/tool
```

You'd have to write a little shell script to get to your system-wide breakdown.

Answer (score 24):

**`readelf -d` recursion**

`redelf -d` produces similar output to `objdump -p` which was mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15520982/895245

But beware that dynamic libraries can depend on other dynamic libraries, to you have to recurse.

Example:

```
readelf -d /bin/ls | grep 'NEEDED'
```

Sample ouptut:

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libacl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Then:

```
$ locate libselinux.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/mnt/debootstrap/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
```

Choose one, and repeat:

```
readelf -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 | grep 'NEEDED'
```

Sample output:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpcre.so.3]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

And so on.

**`/proc/<pid>/maps` for running processes**

This is useful to find all the libraries currently being used by running executables. E.g.:

```
sudo awk '/\.so/{print $6}' /proc/1/maps | sort -u
```

shows all currently loaded dynamic dependencies of `init` (PID `1`):

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.4.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmod.so.2.3.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2.2.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

This method also shows libraries opened with `dlopen`, tested with [this minimal setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/71ab01c5de024d9d97f0e2f0698cbee6c6a9c87a/shared-library/basic/dlopen.c#L16) hacked up with a `sleep(1000)` on Ubuntu 18.04.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/310199/see-currently-loaded-shared-objects-in-linux/1243089

Answer (score 20):

Check shared library dependencies of a program executable

To find out what libraries a particular executable depends on, you can use ldd command. This command invokes dynamic linker to find out library dependencies of an executable.

**> $ ldd /path/to/program**

Note that it is NOT recommended to run ldd with any untrusted third-party executable because some versions of ldd may directly invoke the executable to identify its library dependencies, which can be security risk.

Instead, a safer way to show library dependencies of an unknown application binary is to use the following command.

> **$ objdump -p /path/to/program | grep NEEDED**

[for more info](http://ask.xmodulo.com/check-library-dependency-program-process-linux.html)

Answer (score 10):

On OS X by default there is no `ldd`, `objdump` or `lsof`. As an alternative, try `otool -L`:

```
$ otool -L `which openssl`
/usr/bin/openssl:
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

In this example, using `which openssl` fills in the fully qualified path for the given executable and current user environment.

Answer (score 7):

On UNIX system, suppose binary (executable) name is test. Then we use the following command to list the libraries used in the test is

```
ldd test
```

Answer (score 6):

One more option can be just read the file located at

```
/proc/<pid>/maps
```

For example is the process id is 2601 then the command is

```
cat /proc/2601/maps
```

And the output is like

```
7fb37a8f2000-7fb37a8f4000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4065647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/network_networkmanager.so
7fb37a8f4000-7fb37aaf3000 ---p 00002000 08:06 4065647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/network_networkmanager.so
7fb37aaf3000-7fb37aaf4000 r--p 00001000 08:06 4065647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/network_networkmanager.so
7fb37aaf4000-7fb37aaf5000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 4065647                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/network_networkmanager.so
7fb37aaf5000-7fb37aafe000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4065646                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/config_gnome3.so
7fb37aafe000-7fb37acfd000 ---p 00009000 08:06 4065646                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/config_gnome3.so
7fb37acfd000-7fb37acfe000 r--p 00008000 08:06 4065646                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/config_gnome3.so
7fb37acfe000-7fb37acff000 rw-p 00009000 08:06 4065646                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.15/modules/config_gnome3.so
7fb37acff000-7fb37ad1d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3416761                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1.0.0
7fb37ad1d000-7fb37af1d000 ---p 0001e000 08:06 3416761                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1.0.0
7fb37af1d000-7fb37af1e000 r--p 0001e000 08:06 3416761                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1.0.0
7fb37af1e000-7fb37af1f000 rw-p 0001f000 08:06 3416761                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1.0.0
7fb37af1f000-7fb37af21000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4065186                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
7fb37af21000-7fb37b121000 ---p 00002000 08:06 4065186                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
7fb37b121000-7fb37b122000 r--p 00002000 08:06 4065186                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
7fb37b122000-7fb37b123000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 4065186                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

Answer (score 4):

With `ldd` you can get the libraries that tools use. To rank the usage of libraries for a set of tool you can use something like the following command.

```
ldd /bin/* /usr/bin/* ... | sed -e '/^[^\t]/ d; s/^\t\(.* => \)\?\([^ ]*\) (.*/\2/g' | sort | uniq -c
```

(Here `sed` strips all lines that do not start with a tab and the filters out only the actual libraries. With `sort | uniq -c` you get each library with a count indicating the number of times it occurred.)

You might want to add `sort -g` at the end to get the libraries in order of usage.

Note that you probably get lines two non-library lines with the above command. One of static executables ("not a dynamic executable") and one without any library. The latter is the result of `linux-gate.so.1` which is not a library in your file system but one "supplied" by the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

on ubuntu
print packages related to an executable

```
ldd executable_name|awk '{print $3}'|xargs dpkg -S |awk -F  ":"  '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the path to the executable file -

```
ldd `which <executable>` # back quotes, not single quotes
```

Answer (score 1):

For the **directly linked** libs (what you usually need):

> objdump --private-headers [BINARY] | grep 'NEEDED' | cut --delimiter=' '
> --fields=18-

For **all**:

> ldd [BINARY] | cut --fields=2 | cut --delimiter=' ' --fields=1 | rev | cut --delimiter='/' --fields=1 | rev | sort --unique --version-sort

Answer (score 0):

I found this post very helpful as I needed to investigate dependencies from a 3rd party supplied library (32 vs 64 bit execution path(s)).

I put together a Q&D recursing bash script based on the 'readelf -d' suggestion on a RHEL 6 distro.

It is very basic and will test every dependency every time even if it might have been tested before (i.e very verbose). Output is very basic too.

```
#! /bin/bash

recurse ()
# Param 1 is the nuumber of spaces that the output will be prepended with
# Param 2 full path to library
{
#Use 'readelf -d' to find dependencies
dependencies=$(readelf -d ${2} | grep NEEDED | awk '{ print $5 }' | tr -d '[]')
for d in $dependencies; do
   echo "${1}${d}"
   nm=${d##*/}
   #libstdc++ hack for the '+'-s
   nm1=${nm//"+"/"\+"}
   # /lib /lib64 /usr/lib and /usr/lib are searched
   children=$(locate ${d} | grep -E "(^/(lib|lib64|usr/lib|usr/lib64)/${nm1})")
   rc=$?
   #at least locate... didn't fail
   if [ ${rc} == "0" ] ; then
      #we have at least one dependency
      if [ ${#children[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
         #check the dependeny's dependencies
         for c in $children; do
          recurse "  ${1}" ${c}
         done
      else
         echo "${1}no children found"
      fi
   else
      echo "${1}locate failed for ${d}"
   fi
done
}
# Q&D -- recurse needs 2 params could/should be supplied from cmdline
recurse "" !!full path to library you want to investigate!!
```

redirect the output to a file and grep for 'found' or 'failed'

Use and modify, at your own risk of course, as you wish.