# How to know which dynamic libraries are needed by an ELF?

Tags: header, elf, dll

Is there any tool that reading the headers prints the name of the dynamic libraries required by a Linux executable to run?

I need it to know if there are some weird dependencies (i.e. not very standard) in a binary that I've just built from the source (it's the Python branch of GDB) or it's mostly statically linked. I think that would be easier than reading the makefiles...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show all libraries used by executables on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159/show-all-libraries-used-by-executables-on-linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/usr/bin/ldd` is your friend. Usage:

```
ldd /bin/ls
```

Sample output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd14f79000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f2d875fc000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f2d873f4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2d8702f000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f2d86df1000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2d86bed000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2d8781f000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f2d869e8000)
```

Answer (score 10):

**`readelf -d $executable | grep 'NEEDED'`**

Can be used if you can't run the executable, e.g. if it was cross compiled, or if you don't trust it:

> In  the  usual case, ldd invokes the standard dynamic linker (see ld.so(8)) with the LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS environment variable set to 1, which causes the linker to display the library
>          dependencies.  Be aware, however, that in some circumstances, some versions of ldd may attempt to obtain the dependency information by directly executing the program.  Thus,  you  should
>          never employ ldd on an untrusted executable, since this may result in the execution of arbitrary code.

Example:

```
readelf -d /bin/ls | grep 'NEEDED'
```

Sample ouptut:

```
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libselinux.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libacl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

Note that libraries can depend on other libraries, so you then need:

```
$ locate libselinux.so.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/mnt/debootstrap/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
```

Choose one, and repeat:

```
readelf -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 | grep 'NEEDED'
```

Sample output:

```
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpcre.so.3]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

And so on.

**`/proc/<pid>/maps` for running processes**

This is useful to find all the libraries currently being used by running executables. E.g.:

```
sudo awk '/\.so/{print $6}' /proc/1/maps | sort -u
```

shows all currently loaded dynamic dependencies of `init` (PID `1`):

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.4.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2.24
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmod.so.2.3.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1.1.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0.83.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.23.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2.2.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
```

This method also shows libraries opened with `dlopen`, tested with [this minimal setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/blob/71ab01c5de024d9d97f0e2f0698cbee6c6a9c87a/shared-library/basic/dlopen.c#L16) hacked up with a `sleep(1000)` on Ubuntu 18.04.

See also:

- [Determine direct shared object dependencies of a Linux binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242761/how-do-i-find-the-direct-shared-object-dependencies-of-a-linux-elf-binary)
- [How can I find the dynamic libraries required by an ELF Binary in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612735/how-can-i-find-the-dynamic-libraries-required-by-an-elf-binary-in-c)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run