# Error In Poppler Lib Configuration

Tags: compiler-errors, poppler

I use the following configuration to compile the Poppler library on my Mac OS-X 10.6 with Qt4.7.3:

`./configure --enable-poppler-qt4  --enable-static --enable-poppler-cpp --enable-zlib`

It configures successfully, then I `make` it and then `make install` it.

Then I try to use the static lib in my application as follows:

```
INCLUDEPATH+=/user/local/include/poppler
LIBS+=/usr/local/lib/libpoppler-cpp.a
LIBS+=/usr/local/lib/libpoppler-qt4.a
LIBS+=/usr/local/lib/libpoppler.a
LIBS+=/usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.a
```

But when I compile my application, I get the following error messages:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_FT_Get_Sfnt_Name_Count", referenced from:
      _FcFreeTypeQueryFace in libfontconfig.a(fcfreetype.o)
  "_FT_Outline_Get_CBox", referenced from:
      SplashFTFont::makeGlyph(int, int, int, SplashGlyphBitmap*, int, int, SplashClip*, SplashClipResult*)in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFont.o)
  "_FT_Library_Version", referenced from:
      SplashFTFontEngine::SplashFTFontEngine(bool, bool, bool, FT_LibraryRec_*)in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFontEngine.o)
  "_XML_SetUserData", referenced from:
      _FcConfigParseAndLoad in libfontconfig.a(fcxml.o)
  "_FT_Done_Face", referenced from:
      _FcFreeTypeQuery in libfontconfig.a(fcfreetype.o)
      SplashFTFontFile::~SplashFTFontFile()in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFontFile.o)
      SplashFTFontFile::~SplashFTFontFile()in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFontFile.o)
  "QDomDocument::createCDATASection(QString const&)", referenced from:
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::TextAnnotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
  "_FT_Load_Glyph", referenced from:
      _FcFreeTypeCheckGlyph in libfontconfig.a(fcfreetype.o)
      SplashFTFont::getGlyphAdvance(int)    in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFont.o)
      SplashFTFont::getGlyphPath(int)    in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFont.o)
      SplashFTFont::makeGlyph(int, int, int, SplashGlyphBitmap*, int, int, SplashClip*, SplashClipResult*)in libpoppler.a(SplashFTFont.o)
  "QDomNode::appendChild(QDomNode const&)", referenced from:
      Poppler::DocumentData::addTocChildren(QDomDocument*, QDomNode*, GooList*)     in libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-private.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::Annotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::MovieAnnotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::SoundAnnotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
      Poppler::FileAttachmentAnnotation::store(QDomNode&, QDomDocument&) constin libpoppler-qt4.a(libpoppler_qt4_la-poppler-annotation.o)
```

Am I wrong in either the configuration command or the INCLUDE/LIBPATH variables? Or is there something else going wrong?

Comment: If this is the exact code that you used, isn't there a typo in '/user/local/include/poppler'? Shouldn't it be '/usr/local/include/poppler'?

Answer (score 0):

Poppler has several dependencies which can be listed using the following command:

```
 otool -L /opt/local/lib/libpoppler.19.dylib
```

There are [one](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/32924) or [two](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33184) people with similar issues, as well as [third](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/16056) with historical insight.

Comment: Is there an 'otool' equivalent on Linux?

Comment: There are a few similar commands referenced in an [unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242761/).