# Do I need the Qt toolchain to target a library built with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, static-libraries, toolchain

Is is necessary to use the Qt toolchain (pro files, qmake, etc...) in order to link against a library that was implemented and built with Qt, but itself exposes only a C style API? None of the Qt specific classes are used in the library.

The question applies to both static and dynamic libraries.

Comment: I would think not. Why don't you try without Qt toolchain? You can check dependencies. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242761/how-do-i-find-the-direct-shared-object-dependencies-of-a-linux-elf-binary.

Comment: As long as you have all the dependencies (i.e. the Qt-DLLs) it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is is necessary to use the Qt tools in order to link against a library that was implemented with Qt.

Absolutely not.

---

The Qt tools that generate code are `moc` and `rcc`; if your API doesn't use this then it is quite possible just to use normal 'C' tools.

[moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) is a tool for signals and slots and even C++ code doesn't need to use the Qt tools to link against a Qt library.  You can scan a 'header' for the **MOC** macro with grep, etc in a make rule to know if the `moc` program should be run on the executable.  Following a convention that *class.cc* has a declaration in *class.h* makes this easy.

[rcc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) is a  feature that bundle resources with an application.  However this would be for the Qt application/library and in your case, you just want to link with it.

So, it is even possible to make Qt applications/libraries without `qmake`, etc.  However, your *makefile* will need to fulfil all the portability issues that `qmake`, etc do or you may not care about this.

There are trade-offs to not using the Qt tools.  However, a large majority of Qt features can be used without the tools.