# How to know which shared object is used?

Tags: linux, compilation, linker, shared-libraries

This probably already has an answer but I couldn't find it.

I want to know which shared object is used by the binary (based on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `/etc/ld.so.conf`, etc...). Something similar to the `which` command but for `.so`.

Thanks

Comment: [How do I find the direct shared object dependencies of a Linux binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242761/608639), [How to find out the dynamic libraries executables loads when run](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120015/56041), [How to check what shared libraries are loaded at run time for a given process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5103443/608639), [See currently loaded Shared Objects in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/310199/173513), [How do I know which shared libraries are loaded by an already running process?](https://superuser.com/q/324729/173513), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `ldd` utility. In the same environment you would load your executable  (Same LD_LIBRARY_PATH, e.t.c.)