# undefined symbol: _ZN6tflite12tensor_utils24NeonVectorScalarMultiplyEPKaifPf

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

When I call the tflite file on the Raspberry Pi 3B+, the following error occurred.
here is the code:

```
tflite_path='home/pi/project/model_pb.tflite'
interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=tflite_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()   
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],img_values)
interpreter.invoke()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/project/test.py", line 55, in <module>
    interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=tflite_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py", line 205, in __init__
    _interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_CreateWrapperCPPFromFile(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py", line 28, in <module>
    _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1043, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/_tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6tflite12tensor_utils24NeonVectorScalarMultiplyEPKaifPf
```

I have changed tensorflow version，but it did not work,my python is 3.7.3 and the tensorflow is 1.13.1,it worked well in windows.what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine direct shared object dependencies of a Linux binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242761/determine-direct-shared-object-dependencies-of-a-linux-binary)

Comment: _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.so depends on a function of  another library, not found in your path. https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-support