# Cross-compiling for target with lower version of libstdc++/libgcc

Tags: gcc

I want to use latest gcc compiler, but target pc configuration only has libstdc++/libc suitable for gcc 4.8.

Is there any way to tell compiler to link against older abi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to run my application, built with newer compiler (gcc 6), when I used `-std=gnu++11` flag. It seems explicitly specifying standard version makes compiler link to maximum required version of abi.