# How can I use Debian repositories to install packages in my yocto image (qemux86-64)

Tags: linux, debian, embedded-linux, yocto, apt

So I created an custom Linux image using Yocto project which runs on qemu (qemux86-64). I enabled package-management and installed apt. I wanted to add a Debian repository in my /etc/apt/sources.list file to that I can get packages from the Debian repo.

I edited the sources.list file and added the following:
`deb [trusted=yes] http://debian.mirror.net.in/debian/ stable main`

and ran apt-get update

Things were going fine until I ran into the error:

```
W: GPG error: http://debian.mirror.net.in/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO PUBKEY 658ACFD622F3D138 NO PUBKEY 805C6F00D6C9793
E: Failed to fetch /
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I believe this error is because I don't have any GPG keys, where can I find them? Or is there a way to bypass checking through GPG keys and getting the packages anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from your immediate problem, have you verified that you have libC compatibility?

Comment: @sawdust What do you mean by libC compatibility exactly? If it means that I have C libraries and can compile C/C++ code, then yes. I included dev-tools which support C/C++ development.

Comment: He means that your integrated libC in the Yocto image is the same as the official debian packages are linked with.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM I am not sure about that. How do I check the compatibility?

Comment: "*How do I check the compatibility?*" -- Look in your Yocto build directories or the **/lib64** directory in the target roofs. What's the name and version of the libC shared object file? Then compare that to the Debian distro version that you're using. Or check which shared objects a Debian program would need from your Yocto build: [How to show all shared libraries used by executables in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159/how-to-show-all-shared-libraries-used-by-executables-in-linux)

Comment: I found that a lot of .so files in yocto build directory is common with my linux mint .so files. To be exact, 450 out of 1083 .so files are same as my system's .so files.